# Linux Mint 17: Menu editors can't "move" Main Menu applications

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, mate-desktop, menu, user-interface

Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela 64-bit
MATE 1.10.2

mintmenu 5.6.4

---

Menu editors cannot apply "move" to Mint Menu applications.

**Mozo menu editor**
*(default menu editor, version 1.10.1-1+rafaela)*
Displays custom application order in editor, application order can be moved within Mozo, but order is not applied to actual Main Menu.
This is a screenshot depicting Linux Mint's Main Menu and the Mozo Menu Editor Open side by side:
[image]
Mozo can show, hide and rename applications.

**Alacarte menu editor**
*(manually downloaded from the Software Manager, version 3.10.0-1ubuntu2 )*
Unlike Mozo, displays same order as Mint Menu. Applications cannot be moved within Alacarte, although the "Move" buttons are clickable. Alacarte show, hide and rename edits are available in Alacarte but are not applied to the Main Menu nor applied within Alacarte's list of menu applications.
This is a screenshot of Mint's Main Menu, Alacarte Menu Editor, and an application's Launcher properties accessed through Alacarte:
[image]

**Alacarte** was downloaded after I noticed this problem, as it seemed like a possible solution.

---

Launching **Mozo** via Terminal does not output anything, moving an application in Mozo's editor, however, gives this Terminal error:

```
 /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/Mozo/MainWindow.py:80: Warning: Source ID 45 was not found when attempting to remove it
  gobject.source_remove(self.timer)
```

---

Launching **Alacarte** via Terminal outputs the following errors:

```
(alacarte:7466): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accel_label_set_accel_closure: assertion 'gtk_accel_group_from_accel_closure (accel_closure) != NULL' failed

(alacarte:7466): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accel_label_set_accel_closure: assertion 'gtk_accel_group_from_accel_closure (accel_closure) != NULL' failed
```

Editing an application's name in Alacarte doesn't update in Alacarte or the Main Menu and does not output anything in the Terminal. "Move" buttons are clickable but don't do anything, and don't output anything in the Terminal.

How can I customize the placement of my applications in the Main Menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that by replacing the **mintMenu** menu/item in the panel with a **Main MATE Menu**, my changes in the Mozo menu editor are actually applied.

My process was:

1. Right-click Panel for pop-up menu.
2. Click *"Add to Panel"* in pop-up menu.
3. In *"Add to Panel"* window, select the **Main Menu** item (descriptor: *"The main MATE Menu"*).
4. Use *"Add"* button to add the **Main Menu** to Panel.
5. To move the newly added Main Menu to a more appropriate location, such
   as the far left side of the panel:

   5.1. For each panel item that is in between the Main Menu and the desired location for it: right-click and make sure *"Lock To Panel"*
       is unchecked. Right-click the Main MATE Menu item and choose
       *"move"*.

   5.2. Move the item with the mouse, at the desired location, then click a
   second time to let the item go.

   5.3. Check/re-check any items that you wish to have locked on the panel.
6. Remove the default **mintMenu** menu by right-clicking it and clicking
   *Remove From Panel*.
7. Right-click Main MATE Menu and open **Edit Menu**.
8. Check contents and order of **Main MATE Menu** and **Menu Editor** to make
   sure everything is displaying how it should.

I hope that if anyone else has the problem I had, this solution will work for them.